# Very slow apache request with 100kb JSON blob

Tags: php, laravel, apache, amazon-ec2

**Stack:**
ELB > EC2 > Apache > Laravel

**Problem:**

- When sending a PUT request with a large JSON blob (50-100KB), response times vary from 2seconds to 25seconds
- When sending a PUT request with a small JSON blob (e.g. 100bytes), response time is consistently 300ms

**Troubleshooting:**

- When making a CURL request from my laptop (or web UI), it seems to "hang", but when it actually hits the route code (I have a log there) it executes within 200ms (note that the smaller JSON blobs don't have this "hang" ever)
- If I make a CURL request to ELB or directly to EC2 box, the response times are equal (this should rule out ELB as the issue)
- If I make a CURL request directly from the EC2 box to itself, its blazing fast, there is no "hang" (100ms response)

```
real example from laptop to ec2:

     time_namelookup:  0.000707s
        time_connect:  0.095264s
     time_appconnect:  0.000000s
    time_pretransfer:  0.095421s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  0.201627s
                     ----------
          time_total:  3.734784s


real example from laptop to ec2:

     time_namelookup:  0.000373s
        time_connect:  0.097481s
     time_appconnect:  0.000000s
    time_pretransfer:  0.097572s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  0.205721s
                     ----------
          time_total:  15.709542s

real example from ec2 to itself:

     time_namelookup:  0.000038s
        time_connect:  0.000670s
     time_appconnect:  0.000000s
    time_pretransfer:  0.000722s
       time_redirect:  0.000000s
  time_starttransfer:  0.003291s
                     ----------
          time_total:  0.102886s
```

Comment: What's the code that gets executed in the endpoint you're using to upload your json file? Maybe there's something very inefficient going on there.

Comment: Honestly I've ripped out all the code, it just returns a number.

```Route::put('/path/{id1}/path/{id2}/path', function (Request $request, $id1, $id2) {
    \Log::info('starting route');
    return 7777;
});```

Comment: And the times don't change?

Comment: Correct, still variably slow when 100kb (100,000 character) json blob is sent via PUT

Comment: Lol.. ok so I turned off wifi and tested with tethering from my iphone.. and the "slow" route performs normally now.

Comment: AAAAAAAND i have 50kbps upload on my wifi lol. problem identified

Comment: tldr; restarted router and problem fixed. had 50kbps upload for whatever reason.